# C: integer overflow during evaluation of expression?

Tags: c

In C, I am trying to figure out why my expression isn't always outputting what I am expecting it to. The expression is as follows:

`z = (528*x*8)/(y*1.0e6)`

In a calculator, this expression always gives me the expected result, but when ran in the program it doesn't always do as I expect it to. I don't remember the exact types of all of the variables, but I'm pretty sure that they are all unsigned ints. X and Y can both be pretty large numbers on their own. So, I'm wondering if it is possible that an integer overflow is happening before the expression is fully evaluated?

Comment: Quite possibly.  In this case, you probably want to cast/convert everything to `double` before proceeding with any actual arithmetic.  For the expression you showed, a simple change of `528` to `528.` should take care of everything.

Comment: Why is the LHS defined as `unsigned int` and not a `float`  or `double`?

Comment: Depending on your platform, type `int` probably has a maximum value of 2147483647 before it overflows.  For `unsigned int` the limit is 4294967295.

Comment: _"I don't remember the exact types of all of the variables"_ - but `sizeof(x)` and `sizeof(y)` can give a hint, even though it doesn't tell you if they are signed or not.

Comment: LHS is unsigned int because that is what a previous dev decided was sufficient. Also, it'd be easy enough to check the types, but I don't want to sign in to my work PC right now

Comment: One other important note: I'm doing research right now, not trying to make code changes for the time being. Suggestions for modifications are appreciated, but I'm just trying to see the root cause of it right now

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: So what values of `x` and `y` *are* you entering (specifically). Using a 32-bit `unsigned int` the max value of x before overflow is `1016800`.

Comment: Suggestion: `(528.0 * x * 8.0)`

Comment: Weather Vane, to answer your question, it depends on the context. But, x would definitely be larger than that in many circumstances. Y is a time value, and X would require that I explain a lot about the environment that I can't necessarily disclose

Comment: So in that case, we have conclusively answered your question.  If `x` could "definitely be larger than that in many circumstances", then the intermediate result `528*x*8` will certainly overflow on a machine where type `int` is 32 bits. QED.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity. You said some inputs work and some "pretty large numbers" don't. I was asking for *particular values* that don't give the right result. That is just two numbers, `x` and `y`, and no explanation about the confidential environment is needed.

Comment: I can't be sepecific, sorry. But I've seen enough from the comments to understand what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it is possible that an integer overflow is happening before the expression is fully evaluated?

Yes, that is very possible.

For example, if `x` is 2000000, the subexpression `528*x*8` will overflow.  Theoretically it would evaluate to 8448000000, but that's a 33-bit number.  On most machines, type `int` is either 16 or 32 bits.  (Probably 32 on yours, but still not big enough to hold a 33-bit number like 8448000000.)